# Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError, but i have a key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError,
but I have an API key, and pass it to js. Why it doesn't work?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?Key=MY_API_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```

and

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:380px;"></div>
<script>
    function myMap() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.331917,57.017670),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }
</script>
```

my Test Page: http://shahrkharid.org/GoogleMap.html

[Pic API key from Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJNXE.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter name is case sensitive. You should use `key=...` instead of `Key=...`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key